# Calculating intersection between WFS layer and PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis, wfs, intersection, ogr2ogr

I need to calculate the intersections betweek a WFS layer and the geometries stored in PostGIS table.
Then I should save the geometries of the intersections in a separate PostGIS table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your [WFS layer to a Postgis table](http://anitagraser.com/2012/09/29/wfs-to-postgis-in-one-step/) with the tool [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), and then use [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) or [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html), depending on what you need.

Comment: I've tryed but it's necessary to install the gdal libreries built with the curl support (http://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html) but i don't understand how to do it (i can't find a sequence to install these libraries on my centos 6 server).

Comment: [here are all the GDAL binaries](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/) , choose the appropriate OS and arch. Also here is a [guide to manage packages with YUM.](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html)

Comment: Thank you but, as i wrote, the problem is not to install the gdal libreries but how to built them with the curl support. Do you have a guide for this also?